# Discovery of kinetic gas theory

Tags: history, kinetic-theory

I assume that there was a single person that at a specific day in time was the first to see and understand perfectly clearly that temperature is somehow *identical* with the mean kinetic energy of a bunch of molecules or atoms, and who was able to write this done as a mathematical equation.

Even though this idea grew slowly - over generations of physicists and inside the mind of this one physicist - I believe it became clear to him somehow suddenly (accompanied by an [eureka effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect)).

> Do we know who this person was, and when it happened (roughly)?

Or do you believe this question doesn't make sense or is unanswerable?

Comment: You romanticise science too much but if one scientist deserved to be singled out here, it has to be Boltzmann.

Comment: And to prove @LucJ.Bourhis first point I would say that if you are going to try and pin the kinetic theory of gasses on one person, I would go for James Clark-Maxwell

Comment: That's what I expected. But don't you think there *are* such eureka moments, which are more like an abrupt phase transition than a smooth transition, and which somehow change the scientific world more profoundly? (Maybe kinetic gas theory isn't a good example for that, better would be Einstein's theories of relativity?)

Comment: @BySymmetry: How did you prove Luc's first point by naming Maxwell?

Comment: May this be better on [hsm.se]?

Comment: @HansStricker Because if you over-romanticise history and try and to paint it as the breakthrough of one individual, people don't agree on who that should be

Comment: That's because we just don't know. In the case of relativity - for example - we *do* know.  In the case of kinetic gas theory we *could* know (but don't).

Comment: It is not a matter of priority (even if Maxwell's work preceded the one by Boltzmann), but of fairness: Maxwell and Boltzmann are the parents of kinetic theory in the same way as Newton and Leibniz are the parents of calculus.

Comment: Even with relativity, Einstein noted how much he owed to Maxwell. He was pointed to tensors/Riemannian geometry  by his mathematician friend. When he mentioned his problems to Hilbert, Hilbert wrote the field equations in a week.

Comment: I don't want to doubt that and do pay tribute to both of them, equally. Nevertheless one of them must have been the first, which doesn't affect the contribution of the other.

Comment: @CDCM: It was Hilbert who first wrote down the field equations, Einstein didn't by himself?

Comment: You should find this wiki page good reading : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_priority_dispute I appreciate the irony that we're looking for ordering of events which probably changes depending on whose frame you're looking at ;)

Comment: @CDCM: What do you mean by "whose frame you're looking at"?

Comment: It was a play on words, as in Hilbert would probably say it was himself first. Einstein likewise

Comment: I also read the name of [Clausius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_James_Waterston#Kinetic_theory). But all of them - Clausius, Boltzmann, Clark-Maxwell - came after [Waterston](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jaime_Wisniak/publication/236233406_John_James_Waterston_-_A_Pioneer_of_the_Kinetic_Theory_of_Gases/links/0c960519da1efd388a000000/John-James-Waterston-A-Pioneer-of-the-Kinetic-Theory-of-Gases.pdf).

Comment: To whom it may concern: Find Waterston's collected papers [here](https://ia601607.us.archive.org/2/items/b29487468/b29487468.pdf).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about the History of Science (possibly also the Sociology of Science), not a question about a concept of physics.

Comment: You are right, so please feel free to do so.

Comment: To save my honour: Please have a look at [my answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6610/6422) to this question at History of Science and Mathematics SE.

Answer (score 1):

A sketchy and incomplete account...

Francis Bacon, in his *Novum Organum* (1620) referred to heat as a mode of (particle) motion, but that's not to say that he had anything like the modern conception of Kinetic Theory, and he certainly didn't attempt any mathematical treatment. Daniel Bernoulli (1738) developed a version of kinetic theory that we'd recognise today. John James Waterston (1843) derived a kinetic theory equation for gas pressure (without the  1/3 factor). He also related molecular KE to temperature. His ideas weren't taken seriously. In the late 1850s, Maxwell and Clausius, soon joined by Boltzmann, developed Kinetic Theory as we know it today.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint to Waterston: I never have heard of him before, but he is an extremely interesting scientist.

Comment: He was mentioned by the late Cyril Domb in a series of lectures on statistical mechanics at King's College London, many decades ago. I'd not heard of him before. It might be interesting to compare him with Oliver Heaviside, a much later physicist and engineer, who had a struggle getting his ideas accepted.

Comment: Interesting enough, that both Domb and Waterston were concerned with  phase transitions and critical phenomena (Waterston especially in the context of mental functions, but maybe I'm just talking rubbish).